# Simulation software for KUKA LBR iiwa robot?

Tags: robotic-arm, simulation

I have been working with KUKA LBR iiwa 7 R800 robot, with the KUKA's IDE, which is the 'Sunrise.Workbench'. Since it does not have any virtual platform to verify the code (simulate), it's been quite difficult, as I need to test each code by deploying to the robot.

Can anyone suggest if there is any simulation software available where I can test the code written using the Robotics API in Sunrise.Workbench?

I came across V-REP simulation software, but, not sure if I can use my code in the workbench platform.

Appreciate if anyone can shed some light on it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ROS and related tools. If you want to simulate kinematics of the manipulator, you can visualize it in ROS, by following below steps. 
1. Find a URDF description, or write a one 
2. Visualize it in rviz tool 
3. Write a joint state publisher node, which outputs the joint values from 
your existing code to the visualizer.

look on to [this](https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr)

If you want to do a exact physics simulation you can consider on using Gazebo with ROS.

Comment: The Github project you posted  is for the  KUKA LWR 4+ and not for the LBR iiwa.

Answer (score 1):

I have drivers for the kuka iiwa and integrate the V-REP simulator with my library [**grl**](https://github.com/ahundt/grl), you can even have the simulator drive the physical robot.

Another independent tool is [iiwa_stack](https://github.com/SalvoVirga/iiwa_stack). 
grl can integrate with iiwa_stack as well.